# Klein-Gordon Hamiltonian in terms of Fourier transformed variables

Tags: field-theory, fourier-transform, hamiltonian, complex-numbers, klein-gordon-equation

[image]

The Klein-Gordon Hamiltonian density is a function of four complex variables $\psi , \psi ^* , \pi , \pi ^*$.

Suppose we make the change to Fourier transformed variables. Then the Fourier expansions of $\psi $ and $\pi $ should have completely independent coefficients. It's because they are two independent complex variables.

And the Fourier coefficients in the expansion of $\psi ^*$ and $\pi ^*$ should be dependent on the Fourier coefficients of $\psi $ and $\pi $ respectively.

However the source I'm reading (David Tong's QFT) uses correlated Fourier coefficients for both $\psi $ and $\pi$ as I highlighted in the screenshot. $b$ and $c^{\dagger }$ for $\psi$, and $b^{\dagger}$ and $c$ for $\pi$.

Why would their Fourier transforms depend on each other when they are independent complex variables?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots but Mathjax instead, i.e. type the relevant equations.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker The evolution equation is second order in time. It should require two independent complex fields as the initial state. Then how can $\psi $ and $\pi$ be related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode expansion is **not** a Fourier transform.

The Fourier transform of $\phi$ is
$$\tilde{\phi}(\vec p) = \int \phi(x) \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\vec p \cdot \vec x}\frac{\mathrm{d}^3 x}{(2\pi)^3}$$
and likewise for $\pi$.

The modes in the mode expansion in terms of the Fourier transforms are defined by
\begin{align} 
b(\vec p) & = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{2E_p} \tilde{\phi}(\vec p) + \mathrm{i}\sqrt{\frac{2}{E_p}}\tilde{\pi}(\vec p)\right) \\
c^\dagger(p) & = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{2E_p} \tilde{\phi}(-\vec p) - \mathrm{i}\sqrt{\frac{2}{E_p}}\tilde{\pi}(-\vec p)\right),
\end{align}
i.e. we get two independent complex functions $b,c$ from the two independent Fourier transforms $\tilde{\phi},\tilde{\pi}$.

Comment: Oh so that's why the integral has to be written as a sum of two terms instead of just one term in a Fourier transform. Can you also tell me why the factors ~ $\sqrt {E}$ are there?

Comment: @EggMan It's so that after we turn the modes into creation/annihilation operators the states they create have a "nice" normalization